# Save right panels / tab groups settings to a file

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Every now and then, I probably do a wrong action or wrong keyboard shortcut and I lose the organization of the Photoshop right panel, that I spent some time setting up.

How can I save/export this "right panel layout" **to a file** so that I can restore it in a few seconds if:

- I do a wrong action that messes with these panels
- I reinstall Photoshop on another computer later and I want to reimport my right panel setup

?

I mean the organization of tab groups: `Info/Brushes/Properties`, `Layers/History/Character`, etc.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Window > Workspace > New workspace* seems to work:

[image]

A new `.pws` file will be created in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop ...\Adobe Photoshop ... Settings\WorkSpaces`.